# Jenkins on Mac OS X is slow and crashes

Tags: java, macos, jenkins

I've installed Jenkins on an old Mac Mini (2006), and when I launch it via:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

It starts up and runs, but after some time it stops working (meaning that the browser will just give me a blank white screen)

But when I try to run it via this command (from /Applications/Jenkins):

```
 java -jar jenkins.war
```

Then I get this error in terminal:

```
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Jul 25, 2014 2:23:44 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Jul 25, 2014 2:23:48 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
Jul 25, 2014 2:23:52 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Jenkins home directory: /Users/echoqa/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Jul 25, 2014 2:23:53 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:124)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at Main._main(Main.java:293)
    at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Jul 25, 2014 2:23:53 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@45c1f5b2: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:124)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at Main._main(Main.java:293)
    at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Jul 25, 2014 2:23:53 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: stopped w.{,file:/Users/echoqa/.jenkins/war/},/Users/echoqa/.jenkins/war
Jul 25, 2014 2:23:54 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
Jul 25, 2014 2:23:54 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at Main._main(Main.java:293)
    at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:124)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Jul 25, 2014 2:23:54 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Jul 25, 2014 2:23:54 PM hudson.util.BootFailure publish
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:234)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:267)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:896)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:795)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:78)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:222)
```

I'm thinking that maybe the Mac Mini doesn't have the optimal hardware, but not sure. I tried increase the heapSize in Jenkins but that didn't seem to help either.

The Mac Mini specs are:

Mac OS X 10.6.8
2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
2 GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM

Anyone know why Jenkins is so slow and crashes?

Comment: The system should be OK to run Jenkins, you could start with updating the JRE to a recent version to improve speed. Could you try to post the error that occurs when Jenkins crashs? The error you posted just states that the port is already taken by the already running Jenkins.

Comment: I tried to update to latest Java from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html, but it gave me an error saying that it couldn't be supported on my system...

Answer (score 1):

We are running Jenkins on similar hardware, and it shouldn't be a problem at all. 
It looks to be an error with another process already being bound to port 8080, and there is a good chance that this could be an instance of jenkins you are started previously. If not, check that any other processes are not already taking this port.
 Try putting `localhost:8080` into your browser to check if Jenkins is already running. Alternatively try running `lsof -i:8080` in terminal to see what also may be bound.

Comment: Is your OS version also the same?

Comment: Also I'm confused as to why it starts but then after some time of performing some tasks is when it slows/crashes, if the port was in use then it wouldn't start to begin with

Comment: ChrisWebb - is there some tutorial or post where you followed to get the setup of Jenkins on your environment?

Comment: Yes, that is pretty puzzling. Have you tried using the osx installer? http://flow.apphance.com/introduction/hello-continuous-integration/osx-server/continuous-integration-server